# BeautifulSoup - Remove any rows that contain a 'colspan' attribute Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to remove any **rows** that contain a colspan`<td black="" colspan='3D"8"'>zzz</td>`before it reaches `[i.text.strip` .

**HTML:**

```
<td black="" colspan='3D"8"'>zzz</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
```

**Python:**

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    print(td)
row = [i.text.strip('\\r\\n').strip('=\\r\\nspan>').strip('=\\r\\n').strip('<=\\r\\n/').strip('\\r\\n') for i in td]
```

**Update (Fix)**

```
    for tr in table_rows:
    row = [i.text.strip('\\r\\n').strip('=\\r\\nspan>').strip('=\\r\\n').strip('<=\\r\\n/').strip('\\r\\n') for i in tr.find_all('td') if not i.get('colspan')]
    print(row)
```

I also removed `td = tr.find_all('td')` and added this into the list comprehension. Much appreciated for the help all :)

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: just put a `if not i.get('colspan')` in the list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python list comprehensions support on the fly filter, all you need to do is put `if not i.get('colspan')` in the list comprehension and it'll filter out any element with the colspan attribute before evaluating your `expr`

```py
[expr for i in td if not i.get('colspan')]
```

This should answer your question, however I'm concerned as to how you're building `td`, you seem to **overwrite** `td` in your `for tr in table_rows` loop every iteration. Leaving only the final result of `.find_all` in.

To completely override `td` for all future calculations and filter out all the elements with `colspan` attribute-

```py
td = list(filter(lambda x: not x.get('colspan'), td))
```

Comment: I want to remove it before editing the remaining <td>s 

Some files comedown with colspan's and it's messing with my data, especially as I don't need them

Comment: @Chambo `td = list(filter(lambda x: not x.get('colspan'), td))`